# Docker Attach vs Exec

Tags: docker

I'm using a web socket connection to a container the docker using the Docker API. https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/ (search for websocket)

My only problem is that the container is running a script as a command `/tools/script.sh` and when I use attach I can only see the logs of the script instead of actually connecting to the linux environment.

Is there a way to run a script command and be able to use docker attach?

`docker exec -ti container bash` works but there's no web socket implementation in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The `/v1.24/exec/:cid/start` endpoint uses Dockers hijacked tcp raw-stream format. The streams are described in the [container `/attach` section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#attach-to-a-container).

[Dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) supports hijacking and can expose each as a Node.js stream.